# How to move repositories between groups?

Tags: git, bonobo

I'm playing around with Bonobo Git Server.

In Bonobo, when you create a repository, you can specify a group to place it in.

How do I move a repository to a different group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 'Repositories' page if you have sufficient access there should be an 'Edit' button.  Select that and change the Group value as you would like and then save.